# QGroupBox's child restricts shrink the form

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a multiple screen video player, and I just want to keep 16:9 ratio. There is a qgroupbox as a container of a qwidget which plays video in it. I also use qgroupbox to show selected frame by painting border to green. I can't do this on qwidget because rendered video overlaps that. When I have done with resize, I emit a signal with mouseup event to be able to informed about the resize operation completed. Then I calculate new bounds for qwidget to keep 16:9 ratio and apply this values for qwidget. Here is the image to show you how my app looks like:
[image: application window with 4 qgropboxes]
And here is the code that I use to resize qwidgets:

```
void playBack::OnWindowResized()
{
    float ratio = 16.0f / 9.0f;
    float w = playBackplayer_contList.at(0)->size().width(); //qgroupbox's width
    float h = playBackplayer_contList.at(0)->size().height();//qgroupbox's height
    float currentRatio = w / h;
    float newW = 0;
    float newH = 0;
    if (currentRatio > ratio)
    {
        newH = h;
        newW = h*ratio;
    }
    else if (currentRatio < ratio)
    {
        newW = w;
        newH = w / ratio;
    }

    qDebug() << "NEW WIDGET SIZE: " << (int)newW << " x " << (int)newH;

    for (int i = 0; i < playBackplayer_widgtList.count(); i++)
    {
        playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->setMinimumSize(newW, newH);
        //playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->resize(newW, newH);
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly when I enlarge form, but When I want to shrink, It doesn't allow me to do that. Because I set a minimum value for qwidgets. If I don't use setMinimumSize, use resize(w,h) instead, than orientation problems occur. And here is a example for this issue:

[image: orientation problem when use resize()]

This code below shows ctor and this is where I set the layout:

```
playBack::playBack()
{
    playback_player_1_widget = new QWidget;
    playback_player_2_widget = new QWidget;
    playback_player_3_widget = new QWidget;
    playback_player_4_widget = new QWidget; 

    playback_player_1_widget_cont = new QGroupBox;
    playback_player_2_widget_cont = new QGroupBox;
    playback_player_3_widget_cont = new QGroupBox;
    playback_player_4_widget_cont = new QGroupBox;

    playBackplayer_widgtList.append(playback_player_1_widget);
    playBackplayer_widgtList.append(playback_player_2_widget);
    playBackplayer_widgtList.append(playback_player_3_widget);
    playBackplayer_widgtList.append(playback_player_4_widget);

    playBackplayer_contList.append(playback_player_1_widget_cont);
    playBackplayer_contList.append(playback_player_2_widget_cont);
    playBackplayer_contList.append(playback_player_3_widget_cont);
    playBackplayer_contList.append(playback_player_4_widget_cont);

    int rowcnt = 0;
    int colcnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        playBackplayer_contList.at(i)->setStyleSheet(QString("border:1px solid #000;background-color:#000;"));
        playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color:#f00;"));
        QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;
        layout->setRowStretch(0, 1);
        layout->setColumnStretch(0, 1);
        layout->setRowStretch(2, 1);
        layout->setColumnStretch(2, 1);
        playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->setMinimumWidth(100);
        playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->setMinimumHeight(100);
        playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->setMaximumWidth(10000);
        playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->setMaximumHeight(10000);

        layout->addWidget(playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i),1,1);
        layout->setMargin(0);
        layout->setSpacing(0);

        playBackplayer_contList.at(i)->setLayout(layout);

        mainLayout->addWidget(playBackplayer_contList.at(i), colcnt, rowcnt);

        rowcnt++;
        if (rowcnt % 2 == 0)
        {
            rowcnt = 0;
            colcnt++;
        }

        playBackplayer_widgtList.at(i)->setAcceptDrops(true);
    }
}
```

I have tried various things, I have tried to set size 0 for qwidget before resize, (in mousedownevent) that didn't work, I have tried deleting layout for qgroupbox, after resize happens, create new layout and set it for groupbox, that didn't work, I have tried layout()->adjustSize(), update(), repaint(), all that stuff didn't work. What am I missing? I need helps from you. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: change `mainLayout->addWidget(playBackplayer_contList.at(i), colcnt, rowcnt);` to `mainLayout->addWidget(playBackplayer_contList.at(i), colcnt, rowcnt, Qt::AlignCenter);`

Answer (score 0):

Do away with the grid layout inside the container group boxes. Instead, align and resize the video widget with `setGeometry`

Here is a simple subclass of `QGroupBox` I made that keeps your desired ratio and always stays in the center:

```
class RatioGroupBox : public QGroupBox{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RatioGroupBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QGroupBox (parent){
        setFlat(true);
        setStyleSheet("border:1px solid #000;background-color:#000;");
        setMinimumSize(100, 100);
        setMaximumSize(10000, 10000);
        ratio = 16.0f/9.0f;
        ratioWidget = new QWidget(this);
        ratioWidget->setStyleSheet("background: #f00;");
        ratioWidget->setAcceptDrops(true);
    }

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *){//or you can use your own resize slot
        float w = width();
        float h = height();
        float currentRatio = w/h;
        float newW(0);
        float newH(0);
        if (currentRatio > ratio){
            newH = h;
            newW = h*ratio;
        }
        else if (currentRatio < ratio){
            newW = w;
            newH = w / ratio;
        }

        ratioWidget->setGeometry((w-newW)/2, (h-newH)/2, newW, newH);
    }

private:
    QWidget *ratioWidget;
    float ratio;
};
```

Your entire ctor will become something like:

```
playBack::playBack()
{
    for(int r=0; r<2; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<2; c++){
            RatioGroupBox* playback_player_cont = new RatioGroupBox;
            mainLayout->addWidget(playback_player_cont, c, r);
            playBackplayer_contList.append(playback_player_cont);
        }
    }
}
```

You can of course access your video widgets by exposing `ratioWidget` any way you like. Either by making it public or creating a getter function.